# GCloud - Programmatically creating oauth2 client ids

Tags: google-oauth, gcloud

I'm trying to figure out if I can automate initialization of a project, but to finish it I need an oauth2 client id, which is usually created in GUI as specified in this article [Official google instructions](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849)

I've looked over google cloud shell and [terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6074), but it seems like this is not a possibility, am I correct, or is it just hidden and I have not found it?

Comment: You can neither automate nor mimic user authentication (anywhere). Your question is not clear about what kind of credentials are required, the login/authorization process, how the credentials will be used, etc. In Google Cloud, service accounts are used for machine-to-machine types of authorization. What does this mean? `automate initialization of a project`. Consider reviewing what Terraform offers. Edit your post with more details.

Comment: My only goal is to create OAuth2 client id programatically, and terraform seems to be unable to provide it: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6074

Comment: I recommend that you rewrite your post's title and content to clearly match your problem. As written, I thought your problem was something else.

Comment: You did not specify how you will use OAuth Client IDs. There is an API to create Client IDs for use with IAP. Otherwise, you must use the Google Cloud Console GUI. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients